# SQL 2008 Mirroring, in "restoring" state

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

I'm testing SQL Server 2008 mirroring with a principal, a mirror and a witness. I've gone through the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189047.aspx), restoring the mirror WITH NORECOVERY. The principal says it is synchronized. But the mirror still shows it is in a "restoring..." state. Am I supposed to just leave it like that? Should I run a RESTORE WITH RECOVERY?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it stays in a recovering state.

The mirror isn't directly accessible--it only goes "live" when the main db goes down, and a failover occurs.